# Type checking tool for Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, mypy, typechecking, static-code-analysis

I am trying to run a command that gives some aggregated information on type checking, static code analysis, etc. in some Python source code provided as a directory. If such thing exists, then I would like to add it to a `Makefile` invoked during some [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) pipelines to validate a code base.

I've created this dummy source code file with a runtime issue

#### File *foo_sample.py*

```py
def foo_func(my_num):
    return 1 + my_num


def bar_func():
    foo_func("foo")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar_func()
```

It throws this runtime error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'.

Now I've tried to detect this type error with various tools, but they all fail to find these kind of problems. See the commands in the following list:

- `pyflakes foo_sample.py`,
- `flake8 foo_sample.py`,
- `pylint foo_sample.py`,
- `mypy --check-untyped-defs foo_sample.py`,
- `prospector --strictness veryhigh foo_sample.py`

I know I could detect these issues with `unittest`, but the code base is quite large and untested to some degree. We frequently see runtime errors and address them with a unit test or an integration test. However, we would like to detect them during the execution of a CI pipeline.

Is there a way to run these kind of checks before running the code itself?

How can I avoid to discover these errors at runtime?

Comment: This is a type error, and the best tool to catch that would be `mypy`. Unfortunately, `mypy` will not guess the types if you don't declare the types of your functions. You'd need to add the types in your codebase (which can be a lot of work, yet, it could be a good idea if you have regular errors like these).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [pytype](https://google.github.io/pytype/) useful in this scenario.

When invoking `pytype broken_code.py` on this code:

```py
def foo_func(my_num):
    return 1 + my_num


def bar_func():
    foo_func("foo")

def run_func(my_func):
    my_func()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar_func()
    run_func(bar_func())
```

I correctly find in the output:

- `line 3, in foo_func: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' [unsupported-operands]`
- `line 10, in run_func: 'NoneType' object is not callable [not-callable]`

The command exits with an error so a `Makefile` invoking it could block the execution of a pipeline in a CI environment.

Also, those error checks like `[unsupported-operands]`, etc. can be enabled or disabled with comments in the code, e.g.,

- first disable the checks `# pytype: disable=attribute-error`
- then enable the checks again `# pytype: enable=attribute-error`

See how to use these comments in the documentation, *[Error classes](https://google.github.io/pytype/errors.html)*.

Comment: *pytype* can be installed with `pip3 install pytype` (tried on [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa)).

Answer (score 3):

Undeclared types are considered to be of type `Any`, and are not type checked by `mypy`. A stricter configuration is necessary to make sure `mypy` forces you to set types. Specifically, you need [`disallow_untyped_defs`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-disallow_untyped_defs), which should lead you to this result:

```
$ cat test.py 
def foo_func(my_num: int) -> int:
    return 1 + my_num


def bar_func() -> None:
    foo_func("foo")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar_func()
$ mypy test.py
test.py:6: error: Argument 1 to "foo_func" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

You might also want [`disallow_any_generics`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-disallow_any_generics) and [`warn_return_any`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-warn_return_any). [Example configuration](https://github.com/linz/geospatial-data-lake/blob/773a6ceae977ce67c99a627f47d99a201589389d/setup.cfg).